# Do GL compute shaders trigger TDR if they crash. Not just timeout?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

I'm getting a TDR trigger after 4ms with a GL4.3 compute shader. tdrDelay is currently set to 30 secs, this obviously isn't long enough to get a timeout with the default Windows 11 tdrDelay value let alone my registery value, however the error message is code 7 (RTX A2000, drivers 528.24) which is the generic nVidia TDR occurance.

If there was a bad loop (infiniting) or something, I appreciate this could trigger a timeout, however can TDR's be triggered if the shader crashes (bad data, out of bounds etc) well before the tdrDelay is reached?

In the past I got different error messages if the shader crashes (this was on K2200D iirc, much old drivers, 3XX.XX), however the only error message I seem to get these days is a generic TDR error message (latest nVidia drivers)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, turns out an index out of range index was the culprit when attempting writing to a TBO in the last batch of a workgroup invocation.

I long for the day when compute shaders have better dedicated tools for debugging and drivers supply more descriptive runtime error messages.